# Room Database Migration fails with Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, migrate

I've got a simple SQLite database:

[image: sqllite database]

The corresponding User Entity class looks like follows:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @PrimaryKey
  public int uid;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
  public String firstName;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
  public String lastName;

  public User(int uid, String firstName, String lastName){
      this.uid = uid;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

[image: error pic]

What am I missing? Is the column sequence wrong?
I assumed it is due to the `notNull` annotation which was not set in my entity class, but even with the annotation the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The problem that you assigned a `NN` (Non-Null) value to the "uid" column in SQLite, and that appears in **Expected** section of the error log, although In the migration code (that you didn't show), you didn't explicitly add "`NOT NULL`" statement to the migration, and that what can be seen in the **Found** section of the error log.

This is highlighted in green the top image.

So, it's expected to see something like below, check and modify according to your code:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'User' ADD COLUMN 'uid' INTEGER NOT NULL");
```

NB: Adding error logs in text is more helpful than adding images, although in your case that would help in coloring it for illustration :)