# Room Database Migration: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle <table_name>

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to create a new table using Room Database. I followed the same principles that I used for the first table that I already have in my program, but when the time comes to run the app, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: WaterFountainEntry(com.mpms.relatorioacessibilidadecortec.entities.WaterFountainEntry).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
```

I do gather, by reading this error message, that the program expected a different type from some fields (and probably a different order from them as well), but the thing is that it shouldn't be like that. I made sure to write my migration class exactly as I put the fields in my entity, as follows:

`<Migration Class and Database Creation>`

```
 static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2,3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE WaterFountainEntry (waterFountainID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
                    "schoolEntryID INTEGER NOT NULL, waterFountainHeight DOUBLE NOT NULL, cupHolderHeight DOUBLE NOT NULL," +
                    "waterFountApproximation DOUBLE NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (schoolEntryID) REFERENCES SchoolEntry (cadID))");
        }
    };

    public static ReportDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized (ReportDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), ReportDatabase.class, "ReportDatabase")
                            .addCallback(roomCallback).addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3).build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

`<WaterFountainEntry entity>`

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = SchoolEntry.class, parentColumns = "cadID", childColumns = "schoolEntryID",
        onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE))
public class WaterFountainEntry {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private Integer waterFountainID;
    @NonNull
    private Integer schoolEntryID;
    @NonNull
    private Double waterFountainHeight;
    @NonNull
    private Double cupHolderHeight;
    @NonNull
    private Double waterFountApproximation;

/** getters & setters **/

    public WaterFountainEntry(@NonNull Integer schoolEntryID, @NonNull Double waterFountainHeight,
                              @NonNull Double cupHolderHeight, @NonNull Double waterFountApproximation) {
        this.schoolEntryID = schoolEntryID;
        this.waterFountainHeight = waterFountainHeight;
        this.cupHolderHeight = cupHolderHeight;
        this.waterFountApproximation = waterFountApproximation;
    }
```

So, what could be the error? I really read a lot of documentations and can't find the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple trick to getting the correct SQL is to let Room generate the SQL on your behalf.

Create the Entity(s) then compile (Cntrl+F9) then look in the java generated (from the Android view) and then look for the file that is the same as the @Database class suffixed with _Impl and then find the **createAllTables** method and the SQL is there. It will be exactly what Room will expect.

e.g. :-

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are many differences between the expected & found SQL scripts; taking `cupHolderHeight` column for instance:

**cupHolderHeight column:**

- Expected: `REAL` found: `DOUBLE`  --> Change it to REAL (Basically
  there is no `DOUBLE` type in SQLite)
- Expected `notNull=false`, found `notNull=true`  --> Change it to false (i.e. NULL)

Applying that to your migration SQL script:

Change `cupHolderHeight DOUBLE NOT NULL` into `cupHolderHeight REAL`

You need to go through other columns and do the same. Eventually the script should be like:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE WaterFountainEntry (waterFountainID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "schoolEntryID INTEGER, waterFountainHeight REAL, cupHolderHeight REAL," +
                    "waterFountApproximation REAL, FOREIGN KEY (schoolEntryID) REFERENCES SchoolEntry (cadID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)");
```

You can also consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083514/room-database-migration-fails-with-pre-packaged-database-has-an-invalid-schema/66976814#66976814) for more illustration.

**For arranging and comparing both found & expected scripts:**

You can sort them with a programming script, but Here is a way for sorting them using some tools:

1. Copy the first one (Expected) into a Text Editor:

```
TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
```

2. Replace `},` with `},\n` --> You've to know how to add line break in your text editor:

```
TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
```

Now you'll have each column in a separate row:

3. Do 1 & 2 for the other one (Found):

```
TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
```

4. Now it's easy to sorting them alphabetically and compare one value to another, (Excel can be a tool for this).

Comment: If I am creating the table directly from the entity, them there is no way that I can use a "real" value while creating the entity. Changing `Double` to `Real` won't create any problems at the Migration class?

Comment: You can use `double` normally in entity, and Room database will do the conversion back & forth for you between `REAL` & `double`, but in `database.execSQL()` You need to write SQL script not java script

Answer (score 2):

The Green column is what your migration should look like.

[image]

Please check the highlighted fields and make the changes similar to green as that's your expected result.

Here is the link to [diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) for comparison

Just compare the found and expected result you will know what changes you have to do in your migration

```
 Expected:
    TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='WaterFountainEntry', columns={waterFountainID=Column{name='waterFountainID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountainHeight=Column{name='waterFountainHeight', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, cupHolderHeight=Column{name='cupHolderHeight', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, schoolEntryID=Column{name='schoolEntryID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, waterFountApproximation=Column{name='waterFountApproximation', type='DOUBLE', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='SchoolEntry', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[schoolEntryID], referenceColumnNames=[cadID]}], indices=[]}
```

Comment: You'll get a better diff if you reorder the columns in the same order first (Room doesn't care about the ordering)

Comment: So, how do I reorder the columns? I couldn't find anything of the sorts while researching this

Comment: if you look at the image, the order of the column is different. In the first image waterFountainID is the first column but in the second waterFountainHeight is showing first. 
If you can reorder them it will be easy to compare the difference.

Comment: reordering error text nothing do with the code.

Comment: @CorMatt I have updated the image for you

Comment: @EndUser there is no problem to be added in a different text order? I mean, as long as waterFountainHeight has the same characteristics in what is expected and what was found, it does not matter if it appeared first than waterFountainID?